# LWC lightning-flow No Module Found

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I'm getting the following error when attempting to insert a [lightning-flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow/documentation) (API v55)

> No MODULE named markup://lightning:flow found : [markup://c:...]

Markup is pretty basic, just the component:

```
<template>
    <lightning-flow
        flow-api-name='Survey_customers'
    >
    </lightning-flow>
</template>
```

Comment: This requires API 56, right?

Comment: You can check this out where i have added all the code and screenshots:- [LAUNCH FLOW FROM LIGHTNING WEB COMPONENT](https://salesforcediaries.com/2022/10/09/launch-flow-from-lightning-web-component/)

Comment: @Sanketkumar it is not available in API V55 so far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, Correction- The org was having API v56, but lwc component was having v55 in meta definition.

Answer (score 0):

`lightning-flow` in LWC is a new feature as of the Winter 23 release, which is API v56.0

It is not available in v55.0 or lower